# Dynamically changing file name in org-agenda-export

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I would like to export the agenda view to separate file with a unique name based on the current date. Based on this example code:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("X" agenda "" nil ("agenda.ps")))
)
```

The last argument is the file name so I thought I can put the output of the `concat` function, e.g.:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    '(("X" agenda "" nil (concat (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d") "-agenda.html")))
)
```

Unfortunately, this approach fails since the interpreter takes the `concat` literally, and a string (expected data type) is not generated. I’m not very familiar with LISP, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the last argument is not a filename but rather a list of names, so you must add some extra parentheses.

As you already noted, because of the [quote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html) the list is not evaluated, and it's fine since you don't want to evaluate it, except the last element (`concat` function). To do so you can use [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html):

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
    `(("X" agenda "" nil (,(concat (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d") "-agenda.html"))))
)
```

As a side note, I'm not a specialist of the `org-mode` and I'm just answering the question you asked, but I have a feeling that it is possible to achieve your goal in a more simple way. Not sure how, but maybe you can dig in the documentation of `org-mode` and probably you'll find something interesting.